# GWT RequestFactory - Persist changes to children entities

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

In my application, my entities all stem from a single entity.  I would like to be able to pull the entity, make any changes to the entity (including its children), and then persist that entity and have the changes cascaded - but my basic test is failing.

This is my primary entity that I'm pulling a single instance of and modifying:

```
@Entity
@Component
public class Submission extends EntityAbstract implements IsSerializable
{
  ...   
  /** List of statements in this submission. */
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parentSubmission")
  @NotNull
  @Valid
  private List< Statement > statements = new LinkedList< Statement >( );
  ...
```

The `Statement` and `Submission` classes both contain a localized name.  This is my test scenario where I pull the `Statement` entity I want, and try to make modifications:

```
...
// Custom request context method for Submission:
InstanceRequest< SubmissionProxy, SubmissionProxy > persist( );
...

RequestFactory.getTest( ).get( 1L ).with( Submission.PropertiesALL ).fire( new Receiver< SubmissionProxy >( )
{
  @Override
  public void onSuccess( final SubmissionProxy immutableResponse )
  {
    final Test context = RequestFactory.getTest( );
    final SubmissionProxy submission = context.edit( immutableResponse );

    System.out.println( "received: " + submission.getLocalizedName( ) + ", " + submission.getStatements( ).get( 0 ).getLocalizedName( ) );

    // Make some modifications:
    submission.setLocalizedName( "submission-" + ( ( char )( Random.nextInt( 26 ) + 'A' ) ) );
    submission.getStatements( ).get( 0 ).setLocalizedName( "statementzzz" );

    System.out.println( "persisting: " + submission.getLocalizedName( ) + ", " + submission.getStatements( ).get( 0 ).getLocalizedName( ) );
    context.persist( ).using( submission ).with( Submission.PropertiesALL ).fire( new Receiver< SubmissionProxy >( )
    {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess( final SubmissionProxy immutableSubmission )
      {
        System.out.println( "success: " + submission.getLocalizedName( ) + ", " + immutableSubmission.getStatements( ).get( 0 ).getLocalizedName( ) );
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The results of my test show:

```
received: submissionzzz, statement-name  // Called before making modifications [client]
persisting: submission-E, statementzzz   // Called before persisting changes [client]
server: submission-E, statement-name     // Called before persisting changes [server]
success: submission-E, statement-name    // Called after persisting changes [client]
```

So the changes to the primary entity, `Submission`, are being retained and serialized properly to the server.  But the changes to the child properties, `Statement`, are not serialized to the server so the persistence is incorrect!

**EDIT**:

I still haven't been able to resolve the problem so I created an issue with GWT: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8368&q=requestfactory&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars.  The post contains information about the serialized/deserialized objects and includes the actual payloads that the request factory instance is sending/receiving.

It looks as if the payload and serialization is correct right before it leaves client side, and as soon as it's received on the server side the child data is missing.